# Filter files in folder with FAKE FtpHelper

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am using FAKE FtpHelper with `FtpHelper.uploadAFolder` to upload the `_PublishedWebsites` folder to azure website ftp and I want to exclude the .dlls.

How can I send a whole folder without .dlls with FtpHelper?

Comment: You can use: `CopyDir "source" "temp" (fun f -> f.EndsWith("dll") |> not) ` to first copy the filtered directory to a temp directory and then do the uploadAFolder of the temp dir.